# Can I put an accepted article in Elsevier with IEEE latex format in arxiv?

Tags: arxiv, formatting, ieee, elsevier, latex

I know that [Elsevier policies](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/sharing#acceptedmanuscript) say:

> Authors can share their accepted manuscript: by updating a preprint in arXiv or RePEc with the accepted manuscript

But in the definition of the accepted manuscript, says:

> They do not include other publisher value-added contributions such as copy-editing, formatting, technical enhancements and (if relevant) pagination.

I assume that I cannot upload the accepted manuscript in the Elsevier latex format. I've already uploaded the first version of the paper in the arxiv with IEEEtran latex format. But I am not sure, after acceptance and selecting CC-BY-NC-ND license (it is mandatory for the journal), I can still use IEEEtran latex format or not.

I would appreciate any information about the copyright of formats in the arxiv.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Thanks for your reply. What about IEEE? Do they care?